# Regular expression htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need a simple regular expression to match asp pages and redirect them to another page.

for example

```
/showdetails.asp?id=1334
```

to

```
/page-redirect.php?page=showdetails&id=1334
```

this is what i have so far which doesn't seem to work

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp?id=(.*)$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

where as

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1
```

does seem to work.

---

Never mind solved it myself, needed to escape the ?

```
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp\?id=(.*)$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch`** directive hence none of the proposed solutions will work.

You need to use `mod_rewrite` based rules..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.asp$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours

```
301 ^/(.*)\.asp?id=(.*)$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Correct

```
301 ^/(.*)\.asp\?id=(.*)$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Consider

```
301 ^/([^/]+)\.asp\?id=(\d+)$ /page-redirect.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `?` in `asp?id`, perhaps.